# Angularjs 2 installation Methods

Tags: angularjs, npm

I have one angularjs 2 UI (without node modules) which i have to integrate with my backend. After installing Angular cli, Can i simply do npm install in the angularjs 2 directory folder as it have package.json or create a new app after installing angular cli and then do npm install for some node modules specific to my angularjs project.

Will the first approach Work successfully as it is easier

Comment: Yes. That should work for you. After `npm install` try `ng-serve` in same directory for running the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backendend and frontend repos are in same package.json just serve your app. You can separate these ( in the future it will be more effective ) . So just search your starting command and run the app.